# Transform http:// link as text to a href but dont include <br> tag at the end

Tags: regex, preg-replace, preg-match

So i have this code:

```
preg_replace('/(http[s]?:\/\/[^\s]*[^,\s\.])/i', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $post_text);
```

It allows me to create hyperlinks from links in text. That `[^,\s\.])` in the end is when someone posts something like "Oh hey this is nice link http://google.com." - it gets rid of dot at the end (among other things) and doesn't include her in creating the ahref.

My problem is though when i have a line break just after that link. For example someone posts

"Oh hey this is nice link http://google.com

"

and my script is then feeded with

```
"Oh hey this is nice link http://google.com<br>"
```

Suddenly that `<br>` is included in link and i am very sad cuz that's not what i want :(

I tried this

```
preg_replace('/(http[s]?:\/\/[^\s]*[^,\s\.<br>])/i', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $post_text);
```

but its not correct apparently.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(http[s]?:\/\/[^\s<>]*[^,\s\.<>])
```

Hi,you just should add '< >'

In you last regex,it matched `<br>` by the first `[^\s]*`

Comment: Ah, i tried to ad <> only to the second [] but forgot about the first []. It works, thanks man!